# Handling Sql Custom Exception

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, raiserror

How to identify the custom error message raised from the sql stored procedure with c# code?

Stored Procedure the error will be raised like this

```
RAISERROR (N'This is message %s %d.', -- Message text.
       10, -- Severity,
       1, -- State,
       N'number', -- First argument.
       5); -- Second argument.
```

From the above, how to identify that the error is custom error message. (ie) Something like this

```
try{
   --actual code here
}
catch(SqlException ex)
{
    --how to check here that the exception is custom one
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you raise the error you can provide a MessageId instead of a Message text. This number will be found in the `Number` propertie of the Exception:

SQL:

```
    RAISERROR(50001, 12, 1)
```

C#:

```
    if (sqlException.Number == 50001)
    {
        throw new CustomSQLException(//whatever);
    }
```

Comment: +1, Thanks for the idea. Is is possible to add Number and message both from RAISEERROR itself?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You need to decide which one you provide. Perhaps you could implement a seperate table with the message and querry this table from your Exception class?

Comment: you meant sql table for this ?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on importance of the message you want to provide. In a normal use case I wouldn't do this since you can provide a large range of error numbers.

Comment: Just a note: `Error numbers for user-defined error messages should be greater than 50000.`

Comment: Another note: `Use sp_addmessage to add user-defined error messages and sp_dropmessage to delete user-defined error messages.` Both notes from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx